# Select sequences in a fasta file with more than 300 aa and "C" occurs at least 4 times

Tags: linux, awk, bioinformatics, sequences, fasta

I have a fasta file which contains protein sequences. I'd like to select sequences with more than 300 amino acids and Cysteine (C) amino acid appears more than 4 times.

I've used this command to select sequences with more than 300 aa:

```
 cat 72hDOWN-fasta.fasta | bioawk -c fastx 'length($seq) > 300{ print ">"$name; print $seq }'
```

Some sequence example:

```
  >jgi|Triasp1|216614|CE216613_3477
 MPSLYLTSALGLLSLLPAAQAGWNPNSKDNIVVYWGQDAGSIGQNRLSYYCENAPDVDVI
 NISFLVGITDLNLNLANVGNNCTAFAQDPNLLDCPQVAADIVECQQTYGKTIMMSLFGST
 YTESGFSSSSTAVSAAQEIWAMFGPVQSGNSTPRPFGNAVIDGFDFDLEDPIENNMEPFA
 AELRSLTSAATSKKFYLSAAPQCVYPDASDESFLQGEVAFDWLNIQFYNNGCGTSYYPSG
 YNYATWDNWAKTVSANPNTKLLVGTPASVHAVNFANYFPTNDQLAGAISSSKSYDSFAGV
 MLWDMAQLFGNPGYLDLIVADLGGASTPPPPASTTLSTVTRSSTASTGPTSPPPSGGSVP
 QWGQCGGQGYTGPTQCQSPYTCVVESQWWSSCQ*
```

Comment: Kindly wrap your code in CODE TAGS correctly and let us know seems it is not clear from your post as of now.,

Comment: Is the data a block like you present above or is it a single line? If a block, how are sequences separated from eachother or is there just one sequence in a file?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thank you! I hope its better!

Comment: @JamesBrown it's a block, sequences are separeted by ">" - which is sequence's header

Comment: @M.Sobreiro, nope, you used quote tags. Rather you should use `{}` button for wrapping up your code in code tags in your post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know `bioawk` but I assume it is identical to [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) with some initial parsing and constant definitions.

I would proceed as follows. Assuming you want the find the strings with more then 4 times the letter `C` in and a length of more than 300, then you could do :

```
bioawk -c fastx '
   (length($seq) > 300) && (gsub("C","C",$seq)>4) {
       print ">"$name; print $seq
   }' 72hDOWN-fasta.fasta
```

but this assumes that `seq` is the full character sequence.

The idea behind it is the following. The `gsub` command performs substitutions in strings and returns the total substitutions it did. Hence, if we substitute all characters "C" with "C" we actually did not change the string, but get the total amount of "C"'s in the string back.

> **From the [POSIX standard IEEE Std 1003.1-2017](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13):**
>
> **`gsub(ere, repl[, in])`**: Behave like `sub` (see below), except that it shall replace all occurrences of the regular expression (like
>   the [`ed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html) utility global substitute) in `$0` or in the in argument,
>   when specified.
>
> **`sub(ere, repl[, in  ])`**: Substitute the string `repl` in place of the first instance of the extended regular expression `ere` in string `in`
>   and **return the number of substitutions**. An <ampersand> ( `&`
>   ) appearing in the string `repl` shall be replaced by the string from `in`
>   that matches the ERE. An <ampersand> preceded with a
>   <backslash> shall be interpreted as the literal
>   <ampersand> character. An occurrence of two consecutive
>   <backslash> characters shall be interpreted as just a single
>   literal <backslash> character. Any other occurrence of a
>   <backslash> (for example, preceding any other character) shall
>   be treated as a literal <backslash> character. Note that if `repl`
>   is a string literal (the lexical token STRING; see [Grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_16)), the
>   handling of the <ampersand> character occurs after any lexical
>   processing, including any lexical <backslash>-escape sequence
>   processing. If `in` is specified and it is not an lvalue (see
>   [Expressions in awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_02)), the behavior is undefined. If `in` is omitted, awk
>   shall use the current record (`$0`) in its place.

**Note:** [BioAwk](https://github.com/lh3/bioawk) is based on [Brian Kernighan's awk](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/btl.mirror/) which is documented in ["The AWK Programming Language",
by Al Aho, Brian Kernighan, and Peter Weinberger
(Addison-Wesley, 1988, ISBN 0-201-07981-X)](https://ia802309.us.archive.org/25/items/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7/The_AWK_Programming_Language.pdf)
. I'm not sure if this version is compatible with [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13).

Comment: Thank you so much! It perflectly worked!

Bioawk is an awk extension and it handles with biological format data.